# simple reactjs component having unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

what is the error in this react component  ?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Tasks = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/tasks').then(response => setTasks(response.data));
    return (
      <ul>
        {renderList(tasks)}
      </ul>
    );
  },[]);
};

renderList(tasks) {
  console.log(tasks)
  return <li>dd</li>
}

export default Tasks;
```

I can not figure out the error .. seems easy but i dont know where is my error .

```
    ./src/compononents/Tasks.js
  Line 16:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  14 | };
  15 | 
> 16 | renderList(tasks) {
     |                   ^
  17 |   console.log(tasks)
  18 |   return <li>dd</li>
  19 | }
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing the => So, renderList(tasks) => {

Comment: The `Task` component returns `undefined` since you're returning inside the `useEffect` instead. Then, it looks like you're confusing the [function declaration syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) with the [method definition syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the error in this react component ?

The problem is that the method is outside of the component, and also, the return should be outside of the `useEffect`.

```
// component scope
const Tasks = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/tasks').then(response => setTasks(response.data));
    // can't return JSX inside useEffect
    return (
      <ul>
        {renderList(tasks)}
      </ul>
    );
  },[]);
};
// component scope

// outside component scope
renderList(tasks) {
  console.log(tasks)
  return <li>dd</li>
}
```

Here is the full working code

```
const Tasks = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/tasks').then(response => setTasks(response.data));        
  },[]);

  const renderList = tasks => {
      console.log(tasks)
      return tasks.map(() => <li>dd</li>)
  }

  return (
      <ul>
        {renderList(tasks)}
      </ul>
  );
};
```

But you could make it much more simple like

```
const Tasks = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/tasks').then(response => setTasks(response.data));        
  },[]);

  return (
      <ul>
        {tasks.map(() => <li>dd</li>)}
      </ul>
  );
};
```

Comment: thx , worked ,How react know the function which is the component and allow it to return jsx , and prevent the other one ??

Answer (score 2):

You can't return `JSX` from `useEffect`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/tasks').then(response => setTasks(response.data));
  },[])

  return (tasks.length && <ul>{tasks.map(/*...*/)}</ul>)
```

`useEffect` will only return a function to cleanup. Consider using a `boolean` to conditionally render your `JSX` inside `render`